# Como ejecutar un stored procedure desde un api c#

Tags: c#, api, stored-procedure

Tengo una pequeña aplicacion solo para consultar un dato, yo se que no es lo mejor pero bueno apenas voy aprendiendo

quisiera consultar un storedProcedure desde el controllador de un api, esto es lo que tengo de avance pero al momento de consultarlo en POSTMAN no me regresa ningun dato

> GET api/Stored/{id}?Tractor={Tractor}

no se si es pasarle los paramentros de otra manera o algo estoy haciendo mal

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string Tractor)
    {
        using ( StoredEntities ob = new StoredEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var STractor = new SqlParameter("@Tractor", Tractor);
                var courseList = ob.Database.SqlQuery<tblDatos>("exec MovimientosIphone @Tractor=" + STractor.Value + "").ToList<tblDatos>();
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(JArray.FromObject(courseList).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

fue la unica manera que encontre para parametrizar

Logre hacerlo que ejecute pero al momento de mandar pedir solo me regresa unos corchetes []

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string Tractor)
        {
            using ( StoredEntities ob = new StoredEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    var STractor = new SqlParameter("@Tractor", Tractor);
                    var courseList = ob.Database.SqlQuery<tblDatos>("exec MovimientosIphone @Tractor=" + STractor.Value + "").ToList<tblDatos>();
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent(JArray.FromObject(courseList).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                    };
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }
            
        }
```

El Stored Procedure no es la gran cosa solo una consulta

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MovimientosIphone]
    @Tractor varchar
AS
BEGIN
    Select Top 5
        l.Fecha
       ,l.ClaveTractor
       ,l.Caja
       ,l.RazonSocial As Cliente
       ,l.DescripcionMovimiento
       ,l.Origen
       ,l.Destino
       ,l.Usuario As Coordinador
       ,FechaAlta
From locales l
Inner Join Movimientos m On l.ClaveMovimiento=m.ClaveMovimiento
Where l.ClaveTractor=@Tractor
       And M.Movimiento=1
Order By l.Fecha Desc

END
```

Era un error de datos pero al final pude hacerlo funcionar, no pongo mi respuesta porque la ayuda lo obtuvo el compañero que me guio por eso se lo doy a el.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id, int movimientos)
        {
            using (StoredEntities ob = new StoredEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    var Tractor = new SqlParameter("@Tractor", id);
                    var Mov = new SqlParameter("@Movimiento", movimientos);
                    var courseList = ob.Database.SqlQuery<tblDatos>("EXEC MovimientosIphone "+ Tractor.Value +","+ Mov.Value +"").ToList<tblDatos>();
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent(JArray.FromObject(courseList).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                    };
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No me queda claro cual es el problema, hablas de que te regresa todo en un formato no válido.. ¿qué sería un formato no válido? ¿qué esperas como respuesta a diferencia de lo que estas recibiendo?

Comment: Perdon no me explique correctamente, no me regresa ningun valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es que estás usando Web Api entonces puedes retornar directamente el valor que necesitas, algo mas o menos así:

```
public MovimientosIphone_Result Get(string Tractor,int? id)
    {
        using (StoredEntities storedEntities = new StoredEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var NumUnidad = new SqlParameter("@Numero", Tractor);
                var Mov = new SqlParameter("@Mov", id);
                var courseList = storedEntities.Database.SqlQuery<MovimientosIphone_Result>("exec MovimientosIphone @Tractor, @Movimientos",NumUnidad,Mov).ToList();
                return courseList;
            catch (Exception)
            {
        //loggear excepcion
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

y dependiendo de la versión de web api que uses es posible que los resultados no te los devuelva en formato Json, para ello debes agregar en la clase `App_Start / WebApiConfig.cs` la siguiente instruccion:

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

OJO: solo debes configurarlo en caso de que tu proyecto devuelva los resultados en xml y no en Json.

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por ayudarme he hecho la prueba, pero ahora me arroja

No es posible convert el tipo Generic.List a MovimientosIphone_Result

Comment: intentalo la siguiente linea así: var courseList = storedEntities.Database.SqlQuery<MovimientosIphone_Result>("exec MovimientosIphone, @Tractor="+ NumUnidad.Value +", @Movimientos="+ id.Value+"").ToList();

Comment: Lo he hecho funcionar, pero ahora solo me regresa corchetes "[]" pero no me manda error

Comment: Ya ví, lo que pasa es que estás pasando mal los parametros al Store procedure, intentalo de esta forma:
 var STractor = new SqlParameter("@Tractor", Tractor);
                var courseList = ob.Database.SqlQuery<tblDatos>("exec MovimientosIphone @Tractor",STractor).ToList();